# Does webpack support es6 module natively?

Tags: webpack

I just started learning use webpack as bundler. But to start writing es6 code, it needs a babel-loader to translate es6 to es5.

my confusion is why does webpack needs babel-loader? why it doesn't know how to handle es6 module syntax??

if I'm writing pure es5 code, then it doesn't require any module loader, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not support ES2015 Native modules just yet. However, Webpack 2 will leverage Native module loading that will allow for awesome features like tree-shaking.

You can see an example of this setup [here](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html?m=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ES6/ES2015 in your webpack configurations you would have to create an express server and run 'npm start'. Make sure you set this up in your package.json scripts. Make sure you also have babel-cli and babel-core installed as well. Heres my package.json example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "better-npm-run start",
    "compile": "better-npm-run compile",
    "deploy": "better-npm-run deploy",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && npm cache clean",
  },
  "betterScripts": {
    "start": {
      "command": "babel-node bin/server",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "DEBUG": "app:*"
      }
    },
```

If you want to see an example of using es6 for the webpack configurations, take a look at this git repository: https://github.com/codetony25/react-starter-boilerplate